# Сконвеотировал Qt в py но когда я запускаю ошибки не выводится но и окно не появляется

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

Я сконвертировал `.ui` в `.py`, но когда я запускаю ошибки не выводится, но и окно не появляется

Код 1-го файла, который сконвертировался из `.ui`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'D:\Programs\Wheather.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.14.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(406, 499)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 100, 141, 51))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"color:rgb(255, 174, 0);\n"
"font: 24pt \"MV Boli\";\n"
"background-color: rgb(31, 31, 31);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"    background-color:rgb(79, 79, 79);\n"
"    color:rgb(234, 156, 0);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"    color:rgb(255, 226, 0)\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 160, 401, 151))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color:red;\n"
"background-color:(31, 31, 31);\n"
"font: 12pt \"Fixedsys\";\n"
"font-size: 30px;")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 361, 61))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(255, 174, 0);\n"
"background-color:(31, 31, 31) ;\n"
"font: 75 italic 26pt \"Palatino Linotype\";\n"
"border-color: rgb(41, 141, 13);\n"
"")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "GIVE"))
```

А вот что сделал я:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys
import  pyowm
from wheather import Ui_Dialog

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
win = uic.loadUi("Wheather.ui") 



Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
ui = Ui_Dialog()
ui.setupUi(Dialog)
Dialog.show()



sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Такое ощущение, что `wheather.Ui_Dialog` и был получен из `Wheather.ui`. Смотрите, вы можете: **1)** вручную составить UI виджетами **2)** сделать ui файл и его загрузить (`uic.loadUi`) **3)** используя утилиту из ui сделать виджеты (получится **1)**)

Comment: А как пользоватся этим всем

Comment: Кст, я заметил, что у вас разные библиотеки. В том, что вы сделали используется **pyside2**, а в **wheather.py** используется **pyqt5**. Переписал в вашем коде импорт на `from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets` и окно появилось

Comment: А вы еще чтото переписовали кроме from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант. Если у вас `PySide2` поставьте свои импорты.

```
import sys
#import  pyowm

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
#from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


#from wheather import Ui_Dialog
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(406, 499)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 100, 141, 51))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"color:rgb(255, 174, 0);\n"
"font: 24pt \"MV Boli\";\n"
"background-color: rgb(31, 31, 31);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"    background-color:rgb(79, 79, 79);\n"
"    color:rgb(234, 156, 0);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"    color:rgb(255, 226, 0)\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 160, 401, 151))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color:red;\n"
"background-color:(31, 31, 31);\n"
"font: 12pt \"Fixedsys\";\n"
"font-size: 30px;")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 361, 61))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(255, 174, 0);\n"
"background-color:(31, 31, 31) ;\n"
"font: 75 italic 26pt \"Palatino Linotype\";\n"
"border-color: rgb(41, 141, 13);\n"
"")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "GIVE"))


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#    win = uic.loadUi("Wheather.ui") 
    w = Dialog()
#    ui = Ui_Dialog()
#    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update 1**

**Вариант 2**

**main.py**

```
import sys
#import  pyowm

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
#from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from wheather import Ui_Dialog


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#    win = uic.loadUi("Wheather.ui") 
    w = Dialog()
#    ui = Ui_Dialog()
#    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**wheather.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
#from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(406, 499)
        Dialog.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 100, 141, 51))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("QPushButton{\n"
"color:rgb(255, 174, 0);\n"
"font: 24pt \"MV Boli\";\n"
"background-color: rgb(31, 31, 31);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"    background-color:rgb(79, 79, 79);\n"
"    color:rgb(234, 156, 0);\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"    color:rgb(255, 226, 0)\n"
"\n"
"}\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 160, 401, 151))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color:red;\n"
"background-color:(31, 31, 31);\n"
"font: 12pt \"Fixedsys\";\n"
"font-size: 30px;")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 361, 61))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(255, 174, 0);\n"
"background-color:(31, 31, 31) ;\n"
"font: 75 italic 26pt \"Palatino Linotype\";\n"
"border-color: rgb(41, 141, 13);\n"
"")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "GIVE"))
```

Comment: А в другом коде ты чтото менял

Comment: Нет просто консоль ничего не выводит

Comment: @O2 __ в каком другом ?

Comment: @O2 __  скопируйте мой пример, если у вас PySide2 поставьте свои импорты и запускайте. Я собрал все в ОДИН модуль.

Comment: у меня просто ничего не выводит

Comment: ДА я скопировал но ничего не работает

Comment: @O2 __  опубликуйте пример, который вы скопировали и запускаете и у вас ничего не работает.

Comment: Не работает я делаю все по гайдам

Comment: и у меня все идет не так

Comment: У них когда пишут название своего второго файла у них вспывает окойко как у тебя а у меня нет

Comment: @O2 __  я опубликовал второй вариант, если вам нужны еще варианты опубликуйте модуль  `Wheather.ui`

Comment: @O2 __ вопрос решен?